# Read XMl File to String Array

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a XML File and I want to read the data and assign it to a string array, so Operative would be assign to 1 array and JobLocation to another

```
<Demo>
    <JOBOperatives>
    <Operative>
        <Clock>aaaa</Clock>
        <Name>aaaaa</Name>
        <MobileNumber>00000000010</MobileNumber>
        <OperativeTrade>3</OperativeTrade>
        <OperativeTicket>1</OperativeTicket>
    </Operative>
    </JOBOperatives>
    <JobLocation>
        <UPRN>aaa</UPRN>
        <Address1>aaaa</Address1>
        <Address2>aaaa</Address2>
        <Address3>aaaa</Address3>
        <Address4>aaa</Address4>
        <Address5>aa</Address5>
        <PostCode>JR4 4ED</PostCode>
    </JobLocation>
```

Comment: An element per line like x[0] = "<Demo">; x[1] = "<JOBOperatives>"; or an array for each line?

Answer (score 1):

I take it you mean where each property from the xml is it's own element in the array?

That doesn't seem like a very good data structure, especially as xml schema definitions allow for the items to arrive in any order; your expected indexes could get all screwed up.  A strongly-typed object seems more appropriate and is well supported in .Net.  At very least you should use a dictionary, so the keys are preserved.

In this case the number of items in each tree is very small and you could end up with many of them, so a dictionary is probably not the best choice.  You could do objects, but that would be a lot of extra code just to set it up and I get the impression the xml may come from different sources and be different based on the source (or *something* where the structure could change regularly, hence the initial desire for loosely-typed validation).

Ultimately your destination is a database, so I think in this case I'll show you an example using a dataset:

```
string xml = GetXmlString(); // <Demo><JobOperatives><Operative><Clock>aaaa</Clock>...
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(sr);
```

Play around with that: look in the dataset's `.Tables` collection, at each table's `.TableName` property, `.Columns` collection, and `.Rows` collection, and at each columns `.ColumnName` and `.DataType` properties.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for two arrays. One where each element is an <operative> node and one where each element is a <JobLocation> node.

Comment: Thats correct, unless you know of a better way. I am wanting to read the data validate it then write the data to a SQL Table.

Comment: I know, but even then each element in the array is still a field like Address1, instead of a proper property.  An object or dictionary would be a much better structure.

Comment: Can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 0):

The [OuterXml](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.xml.xmlnode.outerxml.aspx&ei=ooiVSY6WI4aR-gbGhIj_CA&usg=AFQjCNFxTmBHu_b0lHPQrfdn4eCbih3Y5A&sig2=bXH_RNVrjQACTeYc7zLBig) property of the XmlNode class might help you here.